# Save javascript blob object to a file in php

Tags: javascript, php, json, node.js, ecmascript-6

I use an API to get the pdf, the API returns a json string https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=743a5a1d3a8449f79a490d6b91fa11d8, this is the code to render the file in the browser

```
 const uintArray = new Uint8Array(json.result.buffer.data);
 const blob = new Blob([uintArray], {type: json.result.type});
 const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
 iframe.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
 document.querySelector('.result-output').appendChild(iframe);
```

How could I write the pdf to a file using PHP?

Answer (score -1):

I can see you are using javascript to get the data.

After getting the data, you should make a post request to PHP with the data and write that data to a file.

So learn to...

- Send a post from javascript to PHP
- Retrieve post data with PHP
- Write data to a file with PHP

Also... instead of sending the whole blob string to PHP, you could send the URL of the file on the API, and allow PHP to download it directly from the API (if it's possible to access the API from PHP).

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("file.pdf", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, $myFileBlob);
?>
```

Use PHP to write the blob to file.